# json.unmarshall fails when there are new lines in source data

Tags: json, go, struct, deserialization

I am running the below code snippet via Go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type response struct {
    Data1 string `json:"data1"`
    Data2 string `json:"data2"`
}

func main() {
    //source data
    str := `{"data1": "this is 
    test data 1", 
    "data2": "this is test data 2"}`

    res := response{}
    fmt.Println("json string is \n")
    fmt.Println(str)

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &res)

    fmt.Println("structure output is \n")

    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

I am expecting output in res response struct, however I am getting empty responses.

**Current Output:**

```
json string is 

    {"data1": "this is 
        test data 1", 
        "data2": "this is test data 2"}

structure output is 

{ }
```

Is there a way we can get proper structure output via json.Unmarshal?

Comment: Never ignore your errors.

Answer (score 2):

The ignored error from `json.Unmarshal` is

```
Error invalid character '\n' in string literal
```

If you want a newline in data1 change `str` to

```
str := `{"data1": "this is \n test data 1", 
    "data2": "this is test data 2"}`
```

Then output will be

```
structure output is 
{this is 
 test data 1 this is test data 2}
```